# simulating standard normal distribution in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a VBA code that iterates columns and rows and generate standard normal distribution:

```
Sub simulate_log_normal()
Dim i As Integer
Dim dblNorm_S_Dist As Double
ActiveSheet.Cells(34, 4).Select
For i = 34 To 64
    For j = 4 To 23
        Set current_cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select
        Set dlbNorm_S_Dist = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist()
        Set current_cell = dlmNorm_S_Dist
        Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

So it start at cell(34,4) and should generate a standard normal value for each column (column 4 to 23) and then for each row (row 34 to 64).

When I run it on Excel, it says:

```
Compile Error:
Argument not optional
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the normal distribution function requires two inputs (z,cumulative).

Comment: So if I just want a standard normal value and non cumulative value, do I say WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(z, False)??

Comment: and you also do not `Set` a double.  you just assign it.  remove the `Set` in from of the double.  Also when setting a range you do not use `.Select`.  And  when assigning a value to a range you do not use `Set`

Comment: I am not sure.  You need to provide inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I removed Set in front of dlbNorm_S_Dist as you said.
I ran it again, and it gives me this error message:
"Run-time error '13'": Type mismatch" and highlight "Set current_cell = ACtiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select.

Comment: Hi Scott,
So I changed and do not show any error message. This is what I have in the inner for loop:
current_cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Select
dlbNorm_S_Dist = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(Z, False)
current_cell = dlmNorm_S_Dist

It runs perfectly fine. However, it does not show me the actual values in the Excel spreadsheet. I want values like 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.33, etc. to be displayed on cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to do with the Norm_S_Dist function but
try something like this:

```
Sub simulate_log_normal()
Dim i As Integer
Dim dblNorm_S_Dist As Double
For i = 34 To 64
    For j = 4 To 23
        Cells(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(1, True)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much. I just tried but it produces the same values for every cell. For example, every cell from D34 to W64 has value 0.84134. Why wouldn't Norm_S_Dist generate different value for every inner and outer loop?

Comment: Your input x is how much stdv. it is away from the mean, and the outcome of the NORM_S_Dist gives you the area under the left sided area between the graph and the x-axis. Ofc this is for every x the same. 
To generate Random Numbers in accordance with a Normal Distribution use: WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), mean, stdv)

Comment: WorksheetFunction.NormOnv(Rnd(), 0, 1) works perfectly fine! This is exactly what I wanted! ty!

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to use Randomize before using Rnd, otherwise you'll see the same numbers over and over again, each time you'll run the code.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function

They say:"Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer."